# Save GPlay Achievment progress without loging in

Tags: java, android, google-play

Can I save an achievement progress, without being logged in to Google, and the next time I log in, all the achievements I've unlocked in this time are unlocked? I've seen somewhere a site to do so, but I lost it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save it to some local `SQLiteDatabase` or `SharedPreferences`, then sync it when the user logs in.